# Need help identifying two types of fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

please can you identify these two fonts?

Thank you in advance!

[image: STATES OF AMERICA]

[image: THIS IS THE TOP PARTF OF A CERTIFICATE WHERE TEXT IS LOCATED]

[image: CONSULTANTS,]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top two are likely to be custom lettering, not a font. But it's in the style of "fat face" and art nouveau types. Try LTR Federal by van Blokland, Etna by Mark Simonson and ITC Benguiat.

The bottom one might be ITC Benguiat stretched and squashed around.

Recommended also is "In Letters We Trust" talking about banknote security printing, a presentation by Tobias Frere-Jones who is a designer. Lots of tricks are shown, it's on YouTube.

Comment: In fact, thanks to you I just found out that it is ITC Benguiat Pro Bold.